# Data tables in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

Actually I have 3 string[], Named m,m1,m2 respectively. How can i show all the three string[] in one row with three columns. Below is my code

```
    DataTable dts = new DataTable("MyDataTableTable");
    dts.Columns.Add("MyColumn");

   foreach (string values in (m))
     {
        dts.Rows.Add(values);
        foreach (string value in (m1))
              {
                  dts.Rows.Add(value);
              }
        foreach (string valuess in (m2))
              {
                  dts.Rows.Add(valuess);
              }

        }
```

This Code returns the results with one column and three rows. So how can i change it to three columns with one row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure If I understand you correctly but it seems to be you want to see all array data in one separate column. You didn't say how you want to see them so for example I decided to use comma separated strings. Your code should look like:

```
DataTable dts = new DataTable("MyDataTableTable");
// Adding columns
dts.Columns.Add("MyColumn m");
dts.Columns.Add("MyColumn m1");
dts.Columns.Add("MyColumn m2");

// create data for every column per array
string columnM = string.Join(",", m);
string columnM1 = string.Join(",", m1);
string columnM2 = string.Join(",", m2);

dts.Rows.Add(columnM, columnM1, columnM2);
```

Comment: This is what i expected... It works fine.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Suppose, if i have multiple rows. Then how?

Comment: In case with n-count sets of arrays - iterate each set of data and use code snippet starting with comment // create data for every column